# Find $y_i=ax^2_i+bx_i+c$ Using Least Squares

Tags: matlab, least-squares

Let $x=(x_1,...,x_n)$ and $y=(y_1,...,y_n)$ write a code the finds $a,b,c$ the solves $y_i=ax^2_i+bx_i+c$ such that $\int_{0}^1(ax^2+bx+c)dx=0$

So we need to build Ax=b and then use x=pinv(A)b

$\int_{0}^1(ax^2+bx+c)dx=\frac{a}{3}+\frac{b}{2}+c=0$

So $c=-\frac{a}{3}-\frac{b}{2}$

$\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & x_i & x_i^2 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
1 & x_i & x_i^2
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 
a \\
b \\
-\frac{a}{3}-\frac{b}{2}
\end{pmatrix}=b$

what should I put in $b$?

Answer (score 1):

How to do
linear least squares fitting.

To fit
a linear sum of
$m$ functions
$f_k(x), k=1$ to $m$
to $n$ points
$(x_i, y_i), i=1$ to $n$,
we want to find the
$a_k, k=1$ to $m$
so that
$\sum_{k=1}^m a_kf_k(x)
$
best fits the data.

Let
$S
=\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i-\sum_{k=1}^m a_kf_k(x_i))^2$.

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{\partial S}{\partial a_j}
&=D_jS\\
&=D_j\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i-\sum_{k=1}^m a_kf_k(x_i))^2\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^nD_j(y_i-\sum_{k=1}^m a_kf_k(x_i))^2\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n2(y_i-\sum_{k=1}^m a_kf_k(x_i))D_j(y_i-\sum_{k=1}^m a_kf_k(x_i))\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n2(y_i-\sum_{k=1}^m a_kf_k(x_i))(-D_j a_jf_j(x_i))\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n2(y_i-\sum_{k=1}^m a_kf_k(x_i))(- f_j(x_i))\\
&=-2\sum_{i=1}^nf_j(x_i)(y_i-\sum_{k=1}^m a_kf_k(x_i))\\
&=-2\left(\sum_{i=1}^ny_if_j(x_i)-\sum_{i=1}^nf_j(x_i)\sum_{k=1}^m a_kf_k(x_i)\right)\\
&=-2\left(\sum_{i=1}^ny_if_j(x_i)-\sum_{k=1}^m a_k\sum_{i=1}^nf_j(x_i)f_k(x_i)\right)\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore,
if $D_jS = 0$,
then
$\sum_{i=1}^ny_if_j(x_i)
=\sum_{k=1}^m a_k\sum_{i=1}^nf_j(x_i)f_k(x_i)
$.

Doing this
for $j=1$ to $m$
gives $m$ equations
in the $m$ unknowns
$a_1, ..., a_m$.

Example:
To fit a polynomial
of degree $m-1$,
let $f_j(x) = x^{j-1}$.
The equations are then

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{i=1}^ny_ix_i^{j-1}
&=\sum_{k=1}^m a_k\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^{j-1}x_i^{k-1}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^m a_k\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^{k+j-2}\\
\end{array}
$

For a line,
$m=2$
and the equations are,
for
$j = 1, 2$,

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{i=1}^ny_ix_i^{j-1}
&=\sum_{k=1}^2 a_k\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^{k+j-2}\\
&= a_1\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^{j-1}+a_2\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^{j}\\
\end{array}
$

Explicitly these are

$j=1:\sum_{i=1}^ny_i
= a_1n+a_2\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\\
j=2:\sum_{i=1}^nx_iy_i
= a_1\sum_{i=1}^nx_i+a_2\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^{2}\\
$

These should look familiar.

For a quadratic,
$m=3$
and the equations are,
for
$j = 1, 2, 3$,

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{i=1}^ny_ix_i^{j-1}
&=\sum_{k=1}^3 a_k\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^{k+j-2}\\
&= a_1\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^{j-1}+a_2\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^{j}+a_3\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^{j+1}\\
\end{array}
$

Example 2.
To fit a line
through the origin,
$y = ax$,
$m=1$ and
$f_1(x) = x$.
The equation is then
$\sum_{i=1}^ny_ix_i
=a_1\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2
$
so the result is
$a
=\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^nx_iy_i}{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2}
$.